# Repetitive directories in PATH

Tags: python, macos, path, zsh, zshrc

I just reset my mac (2015) to Catalina 10.15.6 and installed python3 via brew following [this](https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/osx/) tutorial. I got it working just fine, created a .zshrc file in ~/ and added brew's location to the PATH. Last night, I was trying to mod my PS1 variable in the .zshrc file (which also has the line: `export PATH='/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:{PATH}` in it. After about 20 mins of working back and forth using `nano .zshrc` and `source .zshrc` I echo'ed my PATH, I got this: `/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` (you get the point).

I assume this is because I ran `source .zshrc` so many times in one session? Can anyone explain/guide me to not run into this issue every time I want to work in my .zshrc file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I was able to manually fix the PATH back to **/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin**. I am just looking to not have to do that again ;)

Comment: does it harm you in any way?

Comment: `export PATH='/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:{PATH}` has an unmatched quote.  Is it exactly like that in the `.zshrc` file?

Answer (score 0):

The usual fix is to check before you add. This is for POSIX `sh` but I guess it should work in Zsh too.

```sh
for d in /sbin /usr/sbin /usr/bin/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin
do
    case :$PATH: in
     *:"$d":*) continue ;;
    esac
    PATH=$d${PATH+":$PATH"}
done
```

In fact all except the last one are probably already on your `PATH` when you start your computer, as part of the system-wide environment configuration.

Comment: haha actually they are! ( will its completely backwards though) Thanks!

Comment: This traverses the list of directories back to front quite on purpose.

Comment: @triplee : In zsh, I would probably parse the array `$path` instead, which makes it easy to catch any position of the directory to be searched for.

Answer (score 0):

.zshrc is also processed again when you just run a new interactive subshell. You usually guard repeated extending of variables (such as PATH) by some controlling variable. My solution goes like this:

```
_SH_ONCE_VERSION=0 
: S{SH_ONCE:=} # Just in case you run with set -u enabled.
export SH_ONCE # It is important to make this one an environment variable
if [[ ${SH_ONCE:=0} != $_SH_ONCE_VERSION ]]
then
  # Do modifications here, which should not be done over and over
  PATH=/what/ever/you/want:$PATH  
  export some_var=$(some_long_running_command) # should not be done on every subshell
  ...
  # Guard against repeated inclusion:
  SH_ONCE=$_SH_ONCE_VERSION
fi
```

From this on, the first time you open a new shell, the modifications are done, but on every subshell, they are skipped.

Now, what happens if during your work, you make some change in this "protected part" of your .zshrc? You sure would like to see your changes applied at least once, even on the risk that i.e. your PATH gets a bit longer. This is where _SH_ONCE_VERSION comes into play. Just increment it by 1:

```
    _SH_ONCE_VERSION=1
```

and the new version is processed exactly once again.

What you should consider: With this strategy, and with respect to the PATH, it obviously works if new directories are added in front of the PATH, not at the end.

Comment: This is a very clean way to safeguard the issue I am having. I will try it and let you know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer posted by tripleee, but using the fact that having zsh makes it easy to come up with a more reliable solution, which catches directories in any place in the path, I would do

```
for dir_to_add in .... # List of directories to be added to the PATH, unless they are there already
do
  if (( ${path[(Ie)$dir_to_add]} ))
  then
    : # Directory already in PATH
  else
    PATH=$PATH:$dir_to_add # or: PATH=$dir_to_add:$PATH
  fi
done
```

Note that the scalar `PATH` and the array `path` are automatically kept in sync.

Explanation: `${A[(Ie)X}` is the index of X in the array A, and 0 if X is not in A.

Answer (score 0):

In zsh, you can set the path to only allow unique values:

```
typeset -U path PATH
```

The `-U` option eliminates duplicates from the `path` array and from the `PATH` variable. The `-U` option works with all regular arrays, and with 'tied parameters' that were set up with `typeset -T`, like `PATH`.

A demonstration:

```
typeset +U path PATH      # +U allows duplicates
PATH=/usr/sbin
echo 1 $PATH
#=>  1 /usr/sbin

PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin
echo 2 $PATH
#=>  2 /usr/sbin:/usr/sbin

path+=(/usr/sbin /bin)
echo 3 $PATH
#=>  3 /usr/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin


typeset -U path PATH      # no duplicates
echo 4 $PATH
#=>  4 /usr/sbin:/bin
echo 5 $path
#=>  5 /usr/sbin /bin

PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin:/bin
echo 6 $PATH
#=>  6 /usr/sbin:/bin

path+=(/usr/sbin /bin)
echo 7 $path
#=>  7 /usr/sbin /bin

path+=(/usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin)
print -l $path
#=>  /usr/sbin
#=>  /bin
#=>  /usr/local/sbin
#=>  /usr/local/bin
```